# Is there a way to deny the ability to cancel a build pipeline Azure Devops?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, permissions, azure-pipelines, devops

I couldn't find a similar question online anywhere but I'm currently looking for a way to prevent an Azure DevOps build pipeline (yaml) from being cancelled.

Once a certain job has started I do not want it to be possible to cancel until that job and the subsequent job have completed as it introduces issues. I tried denying "stop build" permissions but that did not help.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to deny the ability to cancel a build pipeline Azure Devops?

I am afraid there is no such way to achieve this at this moment.

You could add your request for this feature on our UserVoice site (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion), which is our main forum for product suggestions. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps：

[image]